# Loud scary noise when I turn water on

Tags: plumbing

I recently replaced the wax ring on my toilet because it was always getting clogged and most recently it overflowed to the tune of at least 4 shop vac basins worth of water. It spread into the hallway and it's brand new carpet.
So after replacement, bolt down, and water hook up I turned the water back on to the toilet. The valve for this is behind the toilet near the floor. It too was recently replaced this time by a professional. Anyway it started making that scary loud noise like the pipes are shaking somewhere. So I turned it off then back on then off on off on until I found the maximum  spot to run the water before it makes the noise. Now the water is barely dripping into the toilets tank. It takes forever to fill. Also I noticed that I can turn the valve up more if I run the water from the sink in the same bathroom at the same time and this seems to quite the noise. of course this is a temp fix until I hear from one of you guys.
Everything in the tank is new and the noise happens when I open the valve. But it stops if I turn on the water from the sink in the same bathroom rm.

Comment: Water hammer can be a problem, strange it Did not happen in the past. There are water hammer arrestors that may solve the problem. Sold at plumbing and big box stores for 15-20$ some will attach after the valve and the toilet supply connects to the seeds for. Something to try.

Comment: You'll get better answers if you clear up some points. Do you get hammering when the water starts to flow or when it stops? Hammering when you open a valve or while the water is running can indicate an obstruction. The shutoff was recently replaced, did it work without noises at any point? Everything inside the tank is new, does it fill normally in spite of the noise? Disconnecting the flexible hose and running the water into a bucket might be a fruitful test, since if it's quiet you can narrow it down to the toilet. (It's not a pressure assisted toilet, right?)

Comment: Depending on the type of shut off valve, the problem may be a loose valve seat or just a bad valve. I would also try the hose and bucket trick mentioned by Matt.

Comment: These are all helpful ideas and thoughts. I thank you gentlemen. I will try each of your suggestions one at a time. Also I will update my question now.